# How to verify PayPal Webhook signature?

Tags: c#, .net-core, paypal, cryptography

Having trouble validating the Webhook received from PayPal. Not many examples are available and not enough knowledge about encryption is possessed by the integrator to accomplish the task.

The guide being followed is [Webhook notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/notification-messages/).

Not sure what is wrong with the code snippet, the result is always false.

Calling [notifications/verify-webhook-signature](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post) endpoint is also resulting in false.

```
        /// <summary>Verify PayPal Webhook Signature</summary>
        /// <param name="webhookId">0YF54686R9851380C</param>
        /// <param name="transmissionId">785bc690-901d-11ea-8fc5-17f05150a6df</param>
        /// <param name="transmissionTime">2020-05-07T04:44:33Z</param>
        /// <param name="certUrl">https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-.....</param>
        /// <param name="transmissionSignature"></param>
        /// <param name="webHookEvent">"{\"id\":\"WH-5P8216093E7920426-60J97470GW748563B\",\"create_time\":\"2020-05-07T11:43:48.000Z\",....</param>
        private static void VerifyWebhookSignature(string webhookId, string transmissionId, string transmissionTime,
            string certUrl, string transmissionSignature, string webHookEvent)
        {
            Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
            String hash = string.Empty;

            var arrayOfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webHookEvent);
            foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(arrayOfBytes)) hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();

            string expectedSignature = String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", transmissionId,
                transmissionTime, webhookId, hash);

            string certData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(certUrl);
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certData));

            try
            {
                byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(transmissionSignature);
                byte[] expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expectedSignature);

                using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
                {
                    var verified = rsa.VerifyData(
                        expectedBytes,
                        signature,
                        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Verified: {verified}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use encoding utf-8 instread of ascii.  ASCII encoding removes non printable characters.  If that doesn't work I suspect the padding mode of key may also be an issue.  What error are you getting?  See : https://www.google.com/search?q=sha256+json+c%23&rlz=1C1OPRA_enUS563US647&oq=sha256+json+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57.10031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: There is no error, just not verifying. I believe UTF-8 encoding is being used in the code above. We toggled the padding to Pss as well and it was the same result. The data we are using to test is from a real Webhook event, testing is being done as the Webhook is fired, so it theory we should be able to validate it.

Comment: If you were using an invalid key you would of gotten an exception.  Also if you were using the wrong encryption mode you would of gotten an exception.  So I think the key that was used for encryption is not what you are using to decrypt.  Make sure the key and data are correct. One byte off and you will not get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your implementation works, however I'm not sure which implementation you are using to calculate the CRC32 checksum. When using [Crc32.NET](https://github.com/force-net/Crc32.NET) the following snippet is sufficient:

```
var arrayOfBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webHookEvent);
string hash = Crc32Algorithm.Compute(arrayOfBytes).ToString();
```

Thanks for providing it here, I was struggling as well to find a working example!

PS: just discovered the official implementation here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Source/SDK/Api/WebhookEvent.cs#L156

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to manually serialize the json payload. Like so:

```
        var paypalVerifyRequestJsonString = $@"{{
            ""transmission_id"": ""{headerDictionary["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID"][0]}"",
            ""transmission_time"": ""{headerDictionary["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME"][0]}"",
            ""cert_url"": ""{headerDictionary["PAYPAL-CERT-URL"][0]}"",
            ""auth_algo"": ""{headerDictionary["PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO"][0]}"",
            ""transmission_sig"": ""{headerDictionary["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG"][0]}"",
            ""webhook_id"": ""<get from paypal developer dashboard>"",
            ""webhook_event"": {JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)}
            }}";
```

Here is an example I created which works when calling the `notifications/verify-webhook-signature` endpoint https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/562b1740164bae8e41f3bc37f28c5328